# Close Form from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

I have a manager class which launch a Form by using the ShowDialog function. Now, I'm starting an event (like a timer) and would like the manager to close the Form while the timer expire.

I used 2 classes:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Manager
{
    Timer UpdTimer = null;
    readonly int REFRESH_STATUS_TIME_INTERVAL = 5000;
    Form1 form1;

    public Manager()
    {
    }

    public void ManageTheForms()
    {
        UpdTimer = new Timer(REFRESH_STATUS_TIME_INTERVAL);
        // start updating timer
        //UpdTimer.Interval = REFRESH_STATUS_TIME_INTERVAL;
        UpdTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(PriorityUpdTimer_Elapsed);
        UpdTimer.Start();

        form1 = new Form1();
        form1.ShowDialog();


    }

    public void PriorityUpdTimer_Elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdTimer = null;
        form1.closeFormFromAnotherThread();

    }
}
}
```

Form1 Class:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

    }


    delegate void CloseFormFromAnotherThread();

    public void closeFormFromAnotherThread()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            CloseFormFromAnotherThread del = new CloseFormFromAnotherThread(closeFormFromAnotherThread);
            this.Invoke(del, new object[] { });
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Where is your problem here? Is your code throwing any errors?

Comment: As a side node, I do spot a memory leak. UdpTimer will be kept alive by the event subscription, even after the timer has elapsed. You should explicitly unsubscribe- or use a lambda/anonymous method as the subscriber in which you call the close method.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right you want to close the form when the timer stops.

This is the way I do it:

```
System.Threading.Timer formTimer;
```

I use a boolean to see if the timer is still active

```
public Boolean active { get; set; }
```

Create this function:

```
public void timerControl()
{
  if (!active) formTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(TimerProc));
  try
  {
    formTimer.Change(REFRESH_STATUS_TIME_INTERVAL, 0);
  }
  catch {}
  active = true;
}
```

To complete the timer you need the function TimerProc, which is called when there is a new timer created:

```
private void TimerProc(object state)
{
  System.Threading.Timer t = (System.Threading.Timer)state;
  t.Dispose();
  try
  {
    CloseScreen();
  }
  catch{}
}
```

To make it easier for me to program I made the function CloseScreen():

```
public void CloseScreen()
{
  if (InvokeRequired)
  {
    this.Invoke(new Action(CloseScreen), new object[] { });
    return;
  }
  active = false;
  Close();
}
```

Put all these functions in your form class and just use timerControl to activat the timer. You can choose to access it from your Manager class: `Form1.TimerControl();` Or put it in an eventhandler, succes!